# How to apply a function to dataframe using list

Tags: r, lapply, sapply

I have a df

```
id a1 a2
1  x1 y1
2  x2 y2
```

and another dataframe df2

```
id name1 name2
1  a1    b1
1  a2    b2
2  a3    b3
3  a4    b4
3  a5    b5
```

df2 could contain multiple records of unique id's from df1.

I need to join the dataframes in such a way that for each row of df1, i should have one column from first record of df2 and if it exists, second column from second record.

To explain, the output should be like :

```
id a1 a2 n1 n2
1  x1 y1 a1  a2
2  x2 y2 a3 NA
```

For doing this I have split df2 on id using split

```
s <- split(df2, df2$id)
```

but i'm unsure how to use sapply over that. Any pointers for this

Comment: For each id in df1, there could be 1 or 2 records in df2. I need to add two columns in df1 such that If there is one record in df2 for a particular id, one column gets populated and the other is NA, and if both records are present in df2, both columns get populated

Answer (score 1):

If we are not taking the 'name2' column

```
library(dplyr)
df2 %>% 
   filter(id %in% df$id) %>% 
   select(-name2) %>% 
   group_by(id) %>% 
   mutate(rn = paste0("n", row_number())) %>%
   spread(rn, name1) %>%
   left_join(df, .)
#  id a1 a2 n1   n2
#1  1 x1 y1 a1   a2
#2  2 x2 y2 a3 <NA>
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:2, a1 = c("x1", "x2"), a2 = c("y1", "y2"
)), .Names = c("id", "a1", "a2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -2L))


df2 <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L), name1 = c("a1", "a2", 
 "a3", "a4", "a5"), name2 = c("b1", "b2", "b3", "b4", "b5")), .Names = c("id", 
 "name1", "name2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: I get an error saying column id is unknown, whereas ive confirmed both dataframes have same name 'id'. is the parameter used in filter clause actual name or a varaible?

Comment: @hbabbar  Please check the `str` of your data.  I used the 'data' updated in my post

Comment: Yes, both are same names with same types. I'm trying it out with using the statement filter(df2$patient_id %in% df$patient_id) %>%

Comment: @hbabbar  Can you try the same code using the data from my post

Comment: The data was more of a representational form hence i have to change it according to my column names

Comment: @hbabbar Okay, then you change the code also according to that.  I coded based on the example showed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160490/discussion-between-hbabbar-and-akrun).